# Bibliography Internationalization in Quarto

Tags: internationalization, rstudio, quarto, bibliography

I am writing with Quarto in RStudio and wondered if there is any way to change the "and" for "y" in the bibliography. I need to have my bibliography in Spanish.

I am using this in the yml header, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
---
bibliography: writing/references.bib
csl: apa-6th-edition.csl
lang: "es"
---
```

Comment: can you provide a part of your bibliography here with your question?

Comment: For example:@article{Guzmanetal2005,
 title = {The Demography of Latin America and the Caribbean since 1950},
 author = {{Guzmán}, {José Miguel} and {Rodríguez}, Jorge and {Martínez}, Jorge and Abal Medina, Juan Manuel and {González}, Daniela},
 year = {2005},
 date = {2005},
 journal = {Population-E},
 pages = {519--576},
 volume = {61},
 number = {5-6},
 note = {
Citation Key: Guzmanetal2005}
}

Comment: The only way would be to change the csl bibliography style.